# Check the contents of a PostgreSQL data directory

Tags: postgresql

I have found an old unlabeled backup of mine with a PostgreSQL data directory in it. Is it possible to check its contents somehow, without installing PostgreSQL itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily.

You can see what version of PostgreSQL created it by examining the `PG_VERSION` file. Beyond that, you pretty much have to install a compatible PostgreSQL to load and examine the data dir.

You can just compile it (if on unix/linux) or download standalone binaries, you don't have to actually do a full install. Then `pg_ctl -D /path/to/data/directory -w start` to start the server.